# Dynamic css grid layout for undefined amount items

Tags: css, reactjs, css-grid

I am new to web development and attempting to implement a dynamic grid layout to handle an undefined amount of items in a react component. I have a paragraphs array where each element is a line of text, and I have an images array where each element is the file location of the image as a string. It almost works as I want it but except when I want needs to start repeating. Here is the relevant css from my custom.scss styles :

```
  <pre><code>
 .custom-grid-1 {
display: grid;
place-items: center;
grid-gap: 15px;
grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
grid-auto-rows: auto 1fr;
grid-template-areas:
    "paragraph1 image1"
    "paragraph2 paragraph2"
    "paragraph3 paragraph3"
    "image2 paragraph4"
    "paragraph5 paragraph5"
    "paragraph6 image3"
    "image4 paragraph7"
    "paragraph8 image5";

.paragraph {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
}
/*8 paragraphs */
//1
.paragraph:nth-of-type(1) {
    grid-area: paragraph1;
}
.paragraph:nth-of-type(2) {
    grid-area: paragraph2;
}
.paragraph:nth-of-type(3) {
    grid-area: paragraph3;
}
.paragraph:nth-of-type(4) {
    grid-area: paragraph4;
}
.paragraph:nth-of-type(5) {
    grid-area: paragraph5;
}
.paragraph:nth-of-type(6) {
    grid-area: paragraph6;
}
.paragraph:nth-of-type(7) {
    grid-area: paragraph7;
}
.paragraph:nth-of-type(8) {
    grid-area: paragraph8;
}

.image {
    width: 400px;
    height: auto;
}

.image:nth-of-type(1) {
    grid-area: image1;
}
.image:nth-of-type(2) {
    grid-area: image2;
}
.image:nth-of-type(3) {
    grid-area: image3;
}
.image:nth-of-type(4) {
    grid-area: image4;
}
.image:nth-of-type(5) {
    grid-area: image5;
}
  }
</code></pre>  

and here is my react component

 <pre><code>
    import React from "react";

   export default function Grid({ paragraphs, images }) {
    return (
    <div className="custom-grid-1">
        {paragraphs.map((paragraph, idx) => (
            <>
            <p className={`paragraph paragraph${idx + 1})`}>
                    {paragraph}
            </p>
            <img className={`image image${idx + 1}`} src= 
 {images[idx]} alt="" />
            </>
        ))}
    </div>
);
}

  </code></pre>
```

Here is what is rendered in the browser.
[image]
As you can see in the elements it looks like the correct style is added, but below in the styles it only shows

```
 .custom-grid-1 .paragraph {
     font-size: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

when it should be

```
    .custom-grid-1 .paragraph:nth-of-type(8) {
     grid-area: paragraph8;
     }
```

And then the less specific style for the paragraph

Here is a screen shot of how the 9th paragraph (bottom right) is rendered...if it is following the "repeated grid"     like i'm intending it would be rendered in the 1st column. [image]

````
I have tried using
```
.paragraph:nth-of-type(8n + 1) { 
   grid-area: paragraph1; 
   }        
 /**...ect to..*/
paragraph:nth-of-type(8n + 1) {
grid-area: paragraph1; 
} 
```
````

and this stacks the 9th paragraph on top of the 1st paragraph.

I have tried restarting my app to make sure it's not a cacheing issue. Any help here is much appreciated.

Please excuse the formatting of my code snippets

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)